# Warum werden manche trennbare Verben niemals getrennt?

Tags: sentence-structure, separable-verb

Ist es nicht sonderbar, dass sogenannte trennbare Verben sich so selten trennen, und manche überhaupt nicht?

Die Verben *bergsteigen* und *schlafwandeln* zum Beispiel trennen sich nie.

Comment: Ich habe die Überschrift gekürzt, auch wenn sie semantisch jetzt weniger auf Meinung zielt. Nicht ändern wollte ich "komisch" zu "merkwürdig", obwohl ich darüber sinniert habe, und auch nicht die m.E. falsche Prämisse, dass trennbare Verben selten trennbar sind. Die Trennbarkeit ist m.E. meist gegeben, die Ausnahmen selten, aber die Tendenz der Frage finde ich sehr interessant. Evtl. willst Du die Frage selbst noch mal editieren, Überschriften bitte auf den Punkt bringen.

Comment: Der Begriff "trennbare Verben" bezieht sich im Deutschen fast immer auf Kombinationen aus Präposition+Verb wie etwa "umfahren", nicht auf diese Art von Objekt+Verb.

Answer (score 2):

Trennbare Verben werden *immer* getrennt. Wenn sie nicht getrennt werden, sind es keine trennbaren Verben (sic!).

Du scheinst einer Begriffsverwirrung zu unterliegen: Es besteht ein Unterschied zwischen *zusammengesetzten* und *trennbaren* Verben:

- Deine Beispiele "bergsteigen" und "schlafwandeln" sind zwar zusammengesetzte Verben, aber nicht trennbar.
- "entgegenkommen" und "aufblicken" sind dagegen Beispiele für zusammengesetzte, trennbare Verben.

Trennbare Verben sind zwar immer zusammengesetzt, andersherum gilt das allerdings nicht.

Die Trennbarkeit hängt i.A. vom Präfix ab: Verben, die mit "ab-, an-, auf-, aus-, bei-, ein-, her-, hin-, hinein-, los-, mit-, vor-, weg-, zu-, und zurück-" (das ist eine unvollständige Liste) beginnen, sind im Allgemeinen trennbar. Die anderen sollte man im Wörterbuch nachschauen.

Answer (score 2):

Du verwechselst zusammengesetzte Verben mit trennbaren Verben.

Die von dir vorgebrachten Beispiele *»bergsteigen«* und *»schlafwandeln«* werden deshalb niemals getrennt, weil sie nicht trennbar sind. Es sind untrennbare Verben, sie gehören also nicht zu den trennbaren Verben.

Die Verben *»bergsteigen«* und *»schlafwandeln«* sind zusammengesetzt, weil sie durch das Zusammenfügen mehrerer (in diesem Fall jeweils zwei) anderer Wörter entstanden sind:

> der Berg (Substantiv) + steigen (Verb) → bergsteigen (Verb)
> der Schlaf (Substantiv) + wandeln (Verb) → schlafwandeln (Verb)

Der erste Teil muss aber nicht immer ein Substantiv sein:

> schön (Adjektiv) + färben (Verb) → schönfärben (Verb)
> weiter (adverb) + gehen (Verb) → weitergehen (Verb)
> über (Präposition) + setzen (Verb) → übersetzen (Verb)

Dass ein Wort zusammengesetzt ist, bedeutet aber nicht, dass es trennbar ist.

Comment: Die Situation ist noch komplizierter, als ich gewähnt hatte! Heißt es denn nicht: Ich bin am Wochenende berggestiegen, oder ist das ganz falsch?

Comment: @Bernhard: Das ist zwar grammatisch korrekt, aber das Verb *bergsteigen* wird fast ausschließlich im Infinitiv (*"Ich werde bergsteigen." "Karin kann gut bergsteigen"*) und gelegentlich im Partizip (*"die bergsteigenden Touristen"*) verwendet. Den von dir genannten Satz würde man eher mit einem substantivierten Verb bilden: *"Ich war am Wochenende Bergsteigen."*

Answer (score 1):

Deine Frage bezieht sich auf Verben, die aus Substantiv und Verb zusammengesetzt sind.

Substantiv + Verb hast du in folgenden Varianten:

1. Getrennte Fügungen: Schlittschuh laufen.
2. Feste Komposita: Bergsteigen, dienstverpflichten.
3. Unfeste Komposita: Eislaufen, leidtun, kopfstehen.

Während "eislaufen" trennbar ist, ist "bergsteigen" nicht trennbar. Dass ein Verb zusammengesetzt ist, lässt dich also noch nicht wissen, ob es auch trennbar ist.

Bergsteigen gehört zudem zu den Verben, bei denen nur die Infinitivformen wirklich gebräuchlich sind. Einen Satz wie "Sie bergsteigt am Sonntag" hört man wohl eher selten.

Eine Ursache für diese Verwendung liegt oft in der Nähe zu einem Substantivkomposita, aus welchem sie rückgebildet wurden, und dessen Kern noch in der Verwendung gebräuchlich ist.

Answer (score 0):

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4fix-_und_Partikelverben_im_Deutschen#Sonderf%C3%A4lle_bei_der_Verb-Voranstellung

Der Abschnitt, der dem verlinkten vorausgeht, enthält weitere Fälle. Generell scheinen Verben, die wie trennbare Verben aussehen, nicht trennbar zu sein, wenn ihre Bildung auf irgendeine Weise irregulär ist (nämlich auch bei Kombinationen Präfix+Partikel).

Comment: Oh je, so kompliziert! Ich bin nur froh, dass in meiner Klasse bei der U3A eher die Wortbildung betont wurde, also sind an-erkennen, be-vorzug-en und dergleichen fuer mich kein Problem, und das Zusammenschreiben bei ab-fuhr, aus-gesprochen, teil-nehmen, zu-zu-machen usw ist Gott sei Dank fuer den Satzbau unwichtig. Präfixverben erkennt man meistens sofort, und sonst heißt es: Verbzusäte streben die Endstellung an: entweder Er kam um elf Uhr an, oder wie oben zusammengeschrieben. Grenzfälle wie 'bergsteigen' sind ja interessant, aber ich nehme sie gern als Ausnahmen hin!